# Can I safely disable the Software Protection service

Tags: windows-8.1, services

The Software Protection service is Windows 8 has a long, unhelpful description:

**Enables the download, installation and enforcement of digital licenses for Windows and Windows applications. If the service is disabled, the operating system and licensed applications may run in a notification mode. It is strongly recommended that you not disable the Software Protection service.**

What does this even mean? Is there any consequence to disabling the service apart from MS wanting me to? I am definitely NOT interested in getting around intellectual property, I just don't want crapware running on my PC and slowing it down or possibly causing system instability.

On a separate note, the description of various services has become rather more vague compared with Windows XP...and there are many more of them. My best guess this is done to intimidate non-superusers from touching the service, whereas the description should really be about being informative and helpful. Users can then make up their own minds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not disable this service.

The system files are checked if they are the same in system directory and in component store - this ensures system critical files are intact. Windows is constantly monitoring changes in system files (almost no overhead).

Update of system files is also a critical process as vulnerabilities in Windows are discovered almost every day and have to be patched if critical or your system would be exposed to threats.

Additionally running virus protection is also necessary which can be regarded as first line of defense against threats.

Driving fast is wonderful but it is better to drive carefully

Comment: Disabling this service is required to stop windows random reboot when it failed to activate itself.